# How to integrate $\int\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(z-w)\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(w)dw$

Tags: integration, characteristic-functions

> How to integrate $\displaystyle\int\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(z-w)\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(w)dw$ ?

The integral should give a function of $z$, but I don't know how to compute.

$\displaystyle\int\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(z-w)\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(w)dw$

$\displaystyle=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,\frac12)}(z-w)dw=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\mathbf 1_{(-\frac12,0)}(z-w)dw+\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}\mathbf 1_{(0,\frac12)}(z-w)dw$

How to continue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried representing the indicator functions as $\theta(z-w+\frac{1}{2})-\theta(z-w-\frac{1}{2})$ where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function? It might work.

Comment: @Silynn I never heard of that, but thanks wikipedia I know it now. Do you mean really the difference ?

Comment: Yes, because the Heaviside step function is 1 for all values greater than 0. Subtracting the second step function causes the desired behavior; 1 on a specific range of $z-w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having done what you've done up to the left side of the last line, now change variables to $u=z-w$ and do essentially the same thing again.

You can also think of this without integrals: what is the measure of $(-1/2,1/2) \cap \{ w : z - w \in (-1/2,1/2) \}$? Well, the second set is $(z-1/2,z+1/2)$, so what happens? (As your work suggests, it depends on whether $z \in (-1/2,0)$ or $(0,1/2)$.)

Comment: How does the first method work, you change the variables $u=z-w$ and let $w=w$ the Jacobian is $1$ then you will get characteristic function of u, or not ?

Comment: $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(z-w) dw = -\int_{z+1/2}^{z-1/2} f(u) du$. Now plug in what $f$ is in your situation.

Comment: this gives your second method $u\in(-1/2,1/2)$ and $u\in(z-1/2,z+1/2)$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Let me be a bit more explicit. Consider $I=\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} f(z-w) dw$. Let $u=z-w$ then $dw=-du$, $u(1/2)=z-1/2$ and $u(-1/2)=z+1/2$. Therefore $I=-\int_{z+1/2}^{z-1/2} f(u) du$. Then $f$ is the indicator function of $(-1/2,1/2)$, which (after some simple manipulation) reduces the problem to the other method, as you pointed out. You can actually reduce to the second method immediately by noting that the integral of a product of indicator functions is the measure of the intersection of the corresponding sets.

Comment: $z$ is positive: $(-1/2,1/2)\cap(z-1/2,z+1/2)=(-1/2+z,1/2)=1-z$ $\qquad$
$z$ is negative: $(-1/2,1/2)\cap(z-1/2,z+1/2)=(-1/2,z+1/2)=1-|z|$

hence result is $1-|z|$ and $-1\le z\le 1$